# Limit related to exponential $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac1n)^{n^2}/e^n = e^{-1/2}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

How would one show the following limit?

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{e^n} = e^{-1/2}$$

Rewriting this as $\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}}{e}\right)^n$, I expected the limit to be $1$, but I see that I have erroneously assumed that $f(n) \to 1$ implies $(f(n))^n \to 1$.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logarithm of the limit?

Comment: For intuition look at how the log of the top behaves. It is $n^2\log(1+1/n)$, which by Taylor expansion is about $n^2\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Taylor-MacLaurin at order $2$, rewrite is as
$$\mathrm e^{n^2\ln(1+\tfrac1n)-n}=\mathrm e^{n^2\bigl(\tfrac1n-\tfrac1{2n^2}+o\bigl(\tfrac1{n^2}\bigr)\bigr)-n}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac12+o(1)}\to\mathrm e^{-\tfrac12}.$$